# Ordered iteration in map string string

Tags: string, go

In the Go blog, this is how to print the map in order.

http://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

```
      import "sort"

      var m map[int]string
      var keys []int
      for k := range m {
          keys = append(keys, k)
      }
      sort.Ints(keys)
      for _, k := range keys {
          fmt.Println("Key:", k, "Value:", m[k])
      }
```

but what if I have the string keys like `var m map[string]string`

I can't figure out how to print out the string in order(not sorted, in order of string creation in map container)

The example is at my playground http://play.golang.org/p/Tt_CyATTA3
as you can see, it keeps printing the jumbled strings, so I tried map integer values to `map[string]string` but I still could not figure out how to map each elements of `map[string]string`.

http://play.golang.org/p/WsluZ3o4qd

Comment: What do you mean with: _in order of string creation in map container_ you mean by the position they have in `accurate_99`? Can you post a sample input and output?

Comment: Looking at your code ( http://play.golang.org/p/Tt_CyATTA3 ) and your previous question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121331/go-regexp-to-match-either-case-and-keep-the-original-text ) it really seems you're trying to attack a problem that's too complicated and probably requires a more careful design and data structure. Why not ask a question what you're actually trying to achieve instead of asking many small specific question about your implementation (that's likely not going to be well designed)

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://nltk.org/ since it looks like you're trying to do natural language processing which isn't trivial at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the blog mentions that iteration order is randomized:

> *"...When iterating over a map with a range loop, the iteration order is not specified and is not guaranteed to be the same from one iteration to the next"*

The solution is kind of trivial, you have a separate slice with the keys ordered as you need:

> *"...If you require a stable iteration order you must maintain a separate data structure that specifies that order."*

So, to work as you expect, create an extra slice with the correct order and the iterate the result and print in that order.

```
order := []string{"i", "we", "he", ....}

func String(result map[string]string) string { 
   for _, v := range order { 
      if present in result print it, 
   }
   ... print all the Non-Defined at the end 
  return stringValue
}
```

See it running here: http://play.golang.org/p/GsDLXjJ0-E

Comment: THanks, it works, but I just wonder if I really need map container. I did it because go does not support a specific function to find an element in an array which means I need to traverse it everytime I need to find it, so I chose map to locate a certain element. But this gets very complicated, so I might just use array.

Comment: If the array is small enough I think iterating over it will be a very fast operation. On the other hand, using a map is a little  bit faster and if but you don't really need to print you can stick with your initial implementation. The problem comes when you iterate the map anyway ( every time you print it ). Do you really need to keep them in order?